# In TDD, how many tests should I write for a method?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing, tdd

I want implement a method which tells me if the coordinates (x and y) are out of bounds. How many tests should I write? To me it seems to be 5:

1. Test for negative x over bound
2. Test for positive x over bound
3. Test for negative y over bound
4. Test for positive y over bound
5. Test for with bounds

Am I creating redundant tests and should I only have 1 test for each method I want to implement?

Answer (score 9):

This isn't usually the way we think about it in TDD.  It's more: "what test do I need next?"  So, typically, I'd start with (pseudocode)

```
given: bounds (5, 10, 15, 20)
assert: outOfBounds(0, 0)
```

and make that pass with

```
outOfBounds(x, y): return true
```

But I know that's not real yet, so I know I need another test.

```
assert: !outOfBounds(5, 10)
```

So now that fails.  What's the simplest thing that could possibly work?  Maybe

```
outOfBounds(x, y): return x == 0
```

Of course I know I'm still faking it, so I need another test.  This keeps going 'til I'm not faking it any more.  Maybe, in this case, I'd wind up with the same 5 cases you do with your "how many tests" question - but maybe I'll realize I'm done a little sooner than that.

A better question is: **Do I need another test?**

Comment: I don't understand, if you did this couldn't you just end up in an endless loop of a very long case / switch / if elsif statement that covers every possible number? When do you decide it's time to stop writing a table lookup and it's time to write the function more abstractly? What do you achieve by writing the function to cover only the inputs used in the test case? Assert statements never really get that clever, so they can always be cheated. Sincere question to your answer from 9 years ago lol. I'd love to know if you still do it this way.

Comment: @Wumbo, thanks for the question.  Yes, I still do it this way.  The thing is, the developer (you or me) isn't dumb.  We know (a) when the logic block which passes the test is ridiculously complex and (b) when we're starting to get ridiculous in terms of the number of tests.  By writing just one dumb test at a time, we have just a little additional logic at each pass, but at each (green) point, all our tests are passing, so we have a chance to refactor to something more reasonable.  If we start with the full abstract solution, we might not have enough tests.

Answer (score 4):

You need to write sufficient tests to cover off the behaviour you expect to see from your method - no more, no less.

Indeed, if you're practising TDD (as the title suggests) then the behaviour of your method should have been driven out by the tests you wrote, rather than the other way around - so you will already have found the optimal number of tests for the functionality you've written to make them pass. (Though it's common to think of edge cases and failure cases after having driven out the happy-path functionality, which I guess is what's happened here?)

For this specific case, the five tests you've described here sound perfectly sensible to me.

Comment: What about **both** coordinates out of bounds? How do we know if that works? Or one positive and one negative?

Comment: Yep, those sound sensible too. (I wasn't suggesting that the 5 tests are necessarily the comprehensive set; just that the 5 he has here don't sound like overkill.)

Answer (score 1):

A previous employer hired Kent Beck to do a two day seminar on TDD for our group.  And I asked him something very similar, something like "How do you know if you have enough tests?"  His answer was "Do you feel like you have enough tests?"  Of course, he wasn't asking "Do you feel like you've done enough work for today?" or "Would you rather be fishing, and if so, stop writing tests."  His point was, when you think you've exhausted all the ways your unit can be tested and shown to work (or fail) correctly, then you're done.

And of course, when you find a bug in that unit, then you realize "Maybe I wasn't done."  Then you add more tests, and then fix your bug.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, I would revert back to the rule of thumb for testing with good data, bad data, no data. So for a method with one input and a return value, I would think I would need a minimum of three tests. I'd like to hear what others think of this approach.

Answer (score -3):

I would, personally, say that you need one test case.

Within that case you should check all the boundaries that you need to.

So, 1 test 'method' that checks the 5 boundaries.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. If one of those 5 checks fails, you want to know which one, instantly, rather than having to pick through the 5 to figure it out.

Comment: @razlebe I agree 100% that an end user would like to know which check fails, but surely whichever of the 5 individual asserts that fails would log itself?

Comment: That unfortunately depends upon your unit testing framework, and some are truly dreadful. :(

Comment: @razlebe That would make sense as I have only used a limited range of unit testing frameworks (however it makes me glad that it appears I've only used the good ones ;))

I think the important part here is that the checks are actually tested, regardless of the number of test cases/asserts made.